# "The controller must return a response" occurs with @Template annotation

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I have this simple controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Backend;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="app.backend.index")
     * @Template("AppBundle:Backend/Index:index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

But when I visit the page I recieve a `LogicException (The controller must return a response (Array()) given))`

The strange thing is that this problem occured out of nowhere. I have no idea what the reason for this strange behaviour ist. Maybe some of you encountered the same problem?

**Update**
I deleted my vendor and reinstalled all dependencies. I don't know why but it fixed my problem.

Comment: Did you change your controller to return a response instead of an array? What you claim to have done will not have fixed that issue.

Comment: I probably messed up my vendors with PhpStorms Find&Replace function and didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

the controller is not a 'Response()' object, which i believe i why you are receiving this error

Comment: Using the @Tempalte annotation, the controller is allowed to return an array containing the parameters for the view.